# Minimum amount of data enough to generate GeoJSON?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, geojson

So, say I have a mysql database. I assume every row in a table will be a point on a  map. So, when it comes to GeoJSON geometry, it would just use the `point` type. I have a point name, description, lat and long columns.

Is that data enough to generate a suitable GeoJSON object for Google Maps SDK to render a marker in a mobile app?

Exactly, what would the absolute minimum amount of data needed be for a server to generate a GeoJSON object that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the most minimalistic yet valid geojson you can get:

```
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -105.01621,
        39.57422
    ] 
}
```

So all you really need are the coordinates, the rest is optional. This information should be enough to be rendered by the google maps SDK.